# TypeScript in Node with Express. Cannot set a controller's class property with a constructor

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have a Node app with Express implementing TypeScript using Babel.

I tried creating a `UserController` with a private property `_user: User` and set it in the class constructor. The problem is, I keep getting `"message": "Cannot read property '_user' of undefined"` in the output.

This is my class:

```
export class UserController extends CrudController {
    private _user: User;

    constructor() {
        super();
        const user = new User();
        user.id = 1;
        user.email = 'johnappleseed@apple.com';
        user.firstName = 'John';
        user.lastName = 'Appleseed';
        this._user = user; // Setting the global class property
    }

    get(req: Request, res: Response) {
        res.json({ user: this._user });
    }
}
```

The extended class `CrudController` is just an abstract class, but still, here's the code:

```
export abstract class CrudController {
    public abstract get(req: Request, res: Response): void;
}
```

This is my routes file:

```
const userController = new UserController();
router.route('/user')
  .get(userController.get);
```

What could be the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your passing `userController.get` to the router, you will loose the `this`-context of the class, once the router is invoked.

You can solve this by `binding` the method to `userController` and thus setting `this` to the controller (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind for more information):

```
const userController = new UserController();
router.route('/user')
  .get(userController.get.bind(userController);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is this considered a good practice, or is it better if I find a different way to not use class properties?

Comment: I think it is ok in this case - but you may want to consider using a framework like NestJS as it brings very useful features for building a nodejs-api. E.g. concepts like a Controller are already abstracted (see https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers).